# How convert Timezone into specified format?

Tags: java, timezone

my java program want TimeZone like `GMT(+0530)` instead of getting `IST`
Actually my java code like...

```
      String date1=null;
      String formate="IST";
      SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("z");

       SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("Z");
       date1 = gmtFormat.format(sourceFormat.parse(formate));
       System.out.println(date1);//output +0530
```

Problem 1:but Actually i want this format `GMT(+0530)`

Problem 2:The above code working only passing IST giving +0530 and any zone like `EAT,PST` also giving  +0530 only,... but the time will changed `PST = (GMT - 8:00)` 
Please give suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Print format like `GMT(+0530)`  use pattern `'GMT('Z')'` instead of `Z`.

```
SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("'GMT('Z')'");
```

Comment: Thank you...it is working but we pass any zone like PST it is giving GMT(+0530) but it will display on GMT(-08:00)..

Comment: I would refer you this [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/override-a-java-applications-time-zone/5815391) for changing timezone in java.